# C++ Segmentation Fault - tinyXML

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault, tinyxml

I am encountering a segmentation fault when I am trying to execute my code, it compiles without an errors/warnings but gives the error `Segmentation fault` when executed. Here is the code snippet below.

```
XMLElement *pStartTimeStamp = pRoot->FirstChildElement("mobileDevice")->FirstChildElement("RealTimeInformation");
XMLElement *pRealtimeStore = nullptr;
XMLElement *pIter0 = pStartTimeStamp->FirstChildElement("RunID");
while (pIter0 != nullptr) {
    pRealtimeStore = pIter0;
    pIter0 = pIter0->NextSiblingElement("startTimeStamp");
}

if (pRealtimeStore != nullptr) {
    XMLElement *pNewStartTimeStamp = doc.NewElement("startTimeStamp");
    pNewStartTimeStamp->SetText("pNewTimeStamp");
    pStartTimeStamp->InsertAfterChild(pRealtimeStore, pNewStartTimeStamp);

}
```

EDIT:
I tried running `gdb` but it resulted in

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000402ada in tinyxml2::XMLNode::FirstChildElement (this=0x0, value=0x408dd8 "RunID") at tinyxml2.cpp:745
745     for( XMLNode* node=_firstChild; node; node=node->_next ) {
```

When stepping through the code it fails at this line:

```
20      XMLElement *pIter0 = pStartTimeStamp->FirstChildElement("runID");
(gdb) next

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000402ada in tinyxml2::XMLNode::FirstChildElement (this=0x0, value=0x408dd8 "runID") at tinyxml2.cpp:745
745     for( XMLNode* node=_firstChild; node; node=node->_next ) {
```

XML snippet

```
<mobileDevice>
        <mDeviceID></mDeviceID>
        <deviceDescription></deviceDescription>
        <units></units>
        <devicePlacement></devicePlacement>
        <quantisationResolution></quantisationResolution>
        <realTimeInformation>
            <runID/>
            <sampleRate/>
            <startTimeStamp/>
            <endTimeStamp/>
            <data/>
        </realTimeInformation>
        <event>
            <mEventID/>
            <timeStamp/>
            <data/>
            <support/>
        </event>
    </mobileDevice>
```

Comment: which line exactly causes the segmentation fault? use the debugger to find it

Comment: I tried running `gdb` but it resulted in the error `no debugging symbols found`

Comment: Then you have probably built the code without the `-g` flag, which is necessary for gdb

Comment: Rebuilt using `-g` output is in question.

Comment: Then test every pointer for nullptr. But it is most likely pStartTimeStamp.

Comment: um, I was hoping you'd use breakpoint(s) and step through the code block line by line until you find which line exactly causes the error...

Comment: There was a spelling mistake in ("realTimeInformation") r was R... sorry for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the following line is returning a null

```
XMLElement *pStartTimeStamp = pRoot->FirstChildElement("mobileDevice")->FirstChildElement("RealTimeInformation");
```

This is evident by the gdb output saying that "this" pointer is null.

Comment: Is that what `this=0x0` refers to?

Comment: Yes, the method gets called, but it encounters a segment violation as soon as the method tries to access a member.

Comment: Also, it might be helpful if you add the XML file snippet which you are trying to parse.

Comment: There was a spelling mistake in `("realTimeInformation")` `r` was `R`... sorry for this.

Comment: ok i think the problem is that you have "realTimeInformation" in your XML which starts with a lower case and in your code you have "RealTimeInformation" which starts with an upper case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63109/discussion-between-sayu-sekhar-and-colin747).

Answer (score 0):

I bet one of these is null:

```
 pRoot
 pRoot->FirstChildElement("mobileDevice")
 pStartTimeStamp
 pNewStartTimeStamp
```

So how about if you trace something out to find out which.

Comment: Updated question with `gdb` output

Comment: So pStartTime was null because RealTimeInformation wasn't found under mobileDevice. I think?

Comment: There was a spelling mistake in ("realTimeInformation") r was R... sorry for this.

Comment: But the real happy ending is that now you're using the debugger.

Comment: Indeed, was my first time using `gdb` will be of help in the future.